# ios - calling parent function from inside subview

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I have to call a function `updateList` (defined in my ViewController.m) by clicking a button which is inside a UITableViewCell.
How can I do that from inside my UITableViewCell custom class "CustomCell.m"?
I tried using `self.superview`, but I got the TableView containing my cell, not the ViewController in which the function is defined!

Comment: Which class handles the button action? The custom cell class?

Comment: Yes the custom cell class

Comment: This is a good use case for a delegate. Your custom cell class can define a delegate and protocol. The view controller would make itself each cell's delegate and the view controller would implement the custom cell's protocol. The custom cell would notify its delegate whenever the button was tapped.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was wrong...The custom cell class has got a button inside. That button is bound to an action defined in the custom cell class, but I need the action to call a function defined in the viewcontroller.